# Magento 2 change Invoice PDF Font and Add logo and mailing Address in Footer

Tags: magento2, email-templates, invoice, pdf

I want to change Invoice Pdf format.In default magento footer part is not added in pdf invoice.I want to add footer and in footer there will be logo and mailing addres.Also I am looking for update fonts with Open Sans.

I am looking for any solution but not getting exact answer.Should I go through custom module and override pdf module Or is there any solution is available in back-end?

If anyone do it please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried with module

https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2

but this module very complex and provide features if you buy it.I have not used this module and decide to make custom module:

I have created Module with below files:

**Vendorname\Modulename\etc\config.xml**

**Vendorname\Modulename\registration.php**

**Vendorname\Modulename\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"/>
</config>
```

and override file
**Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
     */
    protected $_localeResolver;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $storeManager,
            $localeResolver,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Draw header for item table
     *
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }

    /**
     * Return PDF document
     *
     * @param array|Collection $invoices
     * @return \Zend_Pdf
     */
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->revert();
            }
        }
         $this->_drawFooter($page);
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }



     /**
     * Set font as regular
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Set font as bold
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Set font as italic
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/open-sans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }



     protected function insertLogo(&$page, $store = null)
    {
        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $image = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'sales/identity/logo',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $store
        );
        if ($image) {
            $imagePath = '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
            if ($this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($imagePath)) {
                $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagePath));
                $top = 830;
                //top border of the page
                $widthLimit = 270;
                //half of the page width
                $heightLimit = 270;
                //assuming the image is not a "skyscraper"
                $width = $image->getPixelWidth();
                $height = $image->getPixelHeight();

                //preserving aspect ratio (proportions)
                $ratio = $width / $height;
                if ($ratio > 1 && $width > $widthLimit) {
                    $width = $widthLimit;
                    $height = $width / $ratio;
                } elseif ($ratio < 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                    $height = $heightLimit;
                    $width = $height * $ratio;
                } elseif ($ratio == 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                    $height = $heightLimit;
                    $width = $widthLimit;
                }

                $y1 = $top - $height;
                $y2 = $top;
                $x1 = 158;
                $x2 = $x1 + $width;

                //coordinates after transformation are rounded by Zend
                $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);

                $this->y = $y1 - 10;
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Create new page and assign to PDF object
     *
     * @param  array $settings
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
     */
    public function newPage(array $settings = [])
    {
        /* Add new table head */
        $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
        $this->y = 800;
        if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
        }
        return $page;
    }



    protected function _drawFooter(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
        {
            $this->y =40;    
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(1, 1, 1));
            $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(60, $this->y, 510, $this->y -30);

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.1, 0.1, 0.1));
            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')
             );
            $page->setFont($font, 8);

            $this->y -=15;

            $page->drawText("Mailing Address: ABC Road sector-1 Noida", 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
             $this->y -=10;
            $page->drawText("help@abc.com", 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');


                $store = null;
                $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
                $image = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    'sales/identity/logo',
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $store
                );
                if ($image) {
                    $imagePath = '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
                    if ($this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($imagePath)) {
                        $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagePath));
                        $top = 830;
                        //top border of the page
                        $widthLimit = 270;
                        //half of the page width
                        $heightLimit = 270;
                        //assuming the image is not a "skyscraper"
                        $width = $image->getPixelWidth();
                        $height = $image->getPixelHeight();

                        //preserving aspect ratio (proportions)
                        $ratio = $width / $height;
                        if ($ratio > 1 && $width > $widthLimit) {
                            $width = $widthLimit;
                            $height = $width / $ratio;
                        } elseif ($ratio < 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                            $height = $heightLimit;
                            $width = $height * $ratio;
                        } elseif ($ratio == 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                            $height = $heightLimit;
                            $width = $widthLimit;
                        }

                        $y1 = $top - $height;
                        $y2 = $top;
                        $x1 = 455;
                        $x2 = $x1 + $width;

                        //coordinates after transformation are rounded by Zend
                        $width = 260; 
                        $height = 40;
                        $y  =   $height /2.5;
                        $page->drawImage($image, 80, $y, 35+ $width / 1.5, $y + $height/2);
                    }
                }

                }


}
```

I have also added custom fonts in path lib/internal/open-sans/  and called in invoice.php file.

Comment: Thanks, akgola it's working fine. It is acceptable answer.

Comment: This doesn't work. `Errors during compilation: Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface. Actual type: array;`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the Fooman PdfCustomiser fo Magento 2

https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-pdf-customiser-m2.html

Comment: @lewis,thanks for sharing your recommendation.I have checked it,it looks ok but this is a paid extension,can you please suggest any free extension.

Comment: @akgola maybe you can take a look at https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2